# How does cpu obtain return address from stack

Tags: stack, procedure, machine-code

How does cpu obtains return address from stack   which is pushed by caller function. how he know it is a return address not anything else?

Comment: "how he know it is a return address not anything else?" It doesn't know. If its something else it would jump to some wrong memory address and crash.

Comment: So what machenism we use to return to correct address ?

Comment: I'm just thinking about the same question, and @tkausl's answer isn't helpful - to state the question slightly different: "why does the cpu use this value as a jump address, and the other values are not used as jump addresses?". Maybe a look into assember gives the answer? The instructions should, before the function returns, pop all stack variables from the stack. And then the next element on the stack is the return address.

Comment: @radix the cpu itself has no clue what a value on the stack represents. It just pops a value from the stack and jumps to that address. The compiler (or the programmer if the program is written in Assembly) has to make sure all pushed values are popped before returning.

Answer (score 0):

I had to look it up, but it's sufficiently explained [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack#Return_processing)

So the callee (called subroutine) itself is responsible to pop everything from the stack (own local variables) and to perform the jump to the return address which the caller function provided.

The return address is e.g. the very stack entry after local variables from the callee have been popped (at least in the Wikipedia example - there may be differences on different architectures).

The frame pointer would be a hint for the location to the return address, but can be omitted for performance, so you can't rely on that.

I don't know whether the callee is responsible to remove the parameters which were passed from caller - this may be architecture dependent.

*Update: an assembly example*

At the end of a function (callee), variables that got saved on the stack (i.e. some register values and the return address to the caller) are popped back into the corresponding registers:

```
pop    {r4, r5, r6, pc}
```

On ARM, this gets the four next words on the stack into those registers.
One is the return address which is popped into $PC (program counter).
Thus the execution continues with the instruction at the return address which is popped into $PC.

I can't exactly say how the link register is working. It's supposed to contain a return address (but for nested function calls of course we still need the stack to store several return addresses).